# How can i calculate this limite without using Hopital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

To Study the Differentiability of the this function at 3: $$g(x) = \frac{ x  -  3 }{\,\rule{0pt}{4mm} \sqrt[ 3\, ]{\, x  +  5\, }\,  -  2 } ~~  for ~~ x ~~ \ne ~ 3 , ~~~~~~ g(3) =12.$$
i need to evaluat this limite "**without using Hopital's rule**"
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{x \to  3}\ \left(
\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle\frac{x - 3}
{\rule{0pt}{4mm}\,\sqrt[3\,]{\,x  +  5\,}\,  -  2} -  12}{x - 3}\right)
$$
i've tried several way like : multiplying by the conjugate,.. doesn't work.

Comment: If $a = x+5$ and $b  = 2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ you can try to multiply with $a^2 + ab+b^2$.

Comment: Or, the limit that you want to find is the definition of $g'(3)$. 
You can find the limit by derivating $g(x)$ and substitute $x=3$.

Comment: @Niccolo No to your second comment You need to know that $g$ is differentiable there to do that, but proving differentiability see to be the point of the question.

Comment: @Niccolo I've tried what you've said i get always Indeterminate Forms unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\sqrt[3]{x+5}.$ Then $x\to 3$ gives $y\to 2$ and  $x-3=y^3-8.$
Thus
$${g(x)-12\over x-3}={{y^3-8\over y-2}-12\over y^3-8}
={1\over y-2}-{12\over (y-2)(y^2+2y+4)}\\
={y^2+2y-8\over (y-2)(y^2+2y+4)}={y+4\over y^2+2y+4}\underset{y\to 2}{\longrightarrow}{1\over 2}$$